# Ways to avoid a running Naturalization application being forwarded to another municipality/city

Tags: germany, immigration, passport, naturalization

I have recently made a Naturalization application in Germany (1 month ago) in Bayern and am about to Move to Berlin in 2 months.  And after I do the anmeldung my application will also be forwarded to the Berlin office.

This appears quite hopeless to me since in Berlin my request will not be even looked at before the end of this year due to the centralization of the Einburgerung office in Berlin. Let alone normal cases, Berlin also has a significantly durable process on this topic compared to other cities, and can take years instead of months.

My question is, can you please suggest a few ways to me to keep my application running in Bayern not to be transferred to Berlin? Because otherwise, it would be really hopeless...

--Possible ways that I have thought of so far is mentioning my place in Berlin as a Zweitwohnsitz, but I doubt I can find a landlord to accept doing the Anmeldung with me in Bayern while I don't live there, and don't know about potential risks. Another option also not doing Anmeldiung for a while...

Comment: I don't know if there is a proper legal way to achieve that, I would doubt there is. However, if you delay your registration in the Einwohnermeldeamt in Berlin that should achieve your desired effect. There are probably some rules on how soon you should register there but appointments can be be hard to get in Berlin.

Comment: @quarague delay past 2 weeks can be super costly - **especially** since the landlord has to tell the city that he has a renter, and then they can fine the non-registering renter.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on a legal greyzone and Berlin's notoriously inefficient bureaucracy. As @Trish noted, you are legally required to register your new residence within two weeks [§ 17 BMG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bmg/__17.html). In some (most?) German states you can just walk into a Bürgeramt and register your new residence so it is perfectly straightforward to do that within two weeks and that is expected.

This is not the case in Berlin, you need to get an appointment to register and these are hard to get. I just searched online for Bürgeramt in Berlin, picked [one](https://service.berlin.de/standort/122231/) and then you can choose the service your want (register new residence) and look at the available appointments. Right now on July 7th there were appointments available on exactly one date, September 1st. Note that this is nowhere near within two weeks.

To my knowledge, if you have an appointment at the Bürgeramt to register your new residence than current legal opinion is that you did fullfill the two weeks requirement regardless of when the appointment actually is. After all it is not your fault if the city doesn't offer a faster registration.

Answer (score 2):

### Don't move.

Your application is by law to be handled by the office that is responsible for your primary place of residence. The only lawful way to keep your primary place of residence at your old residence is to not move your primary place of residence.

Not (starting the process of) informing Berlin within **two weeks** that you are now a resident is violating [§ 17 BMG.](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bmg/__17.html) Also, claiming a secondary residence when it is your first is a violation of [§ 21 BMG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bmg/__21.html). [§ 54 BMG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bmg/__54.html) regulates that it is a misdemeanor to not handle the Anmeldung properly.

Comment: I have to move unfortunately because of my job. What if it's a temporary flat that the landlord also does not allow me Anmeldung since it's temporary?

Comment: The law doesn't have such a loophole. Even if time limit is intended,  Anmeldung is mandatory.

Comment: @Triwh what I am practically homeless and someone is just helping me out by renting me a temporary room and being clear with me that I cannot do Anmeldung for it?

Comment: @azerila not giving the paperwork for an Anmeldung is illegal, not attempting to do the Anmeldung is violating the law. The landlord **has** to give paperwork, you have to get yourself a date to perform the paperwork.

Comment: then how do so many people rent places that are not allowed by the landlords to do Anmeldung for and get away with it. It is something that is happening on a countless basis in Germany everywhere

Comment: @azerila WKKDKR - Wo kein Kläger da kein Richter (where there is no applicant, there's no judge)